# "Using" vs "by using"

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis

> You can do whatever you are thinking of using a nested table for using
>   CSS and clean markup.

— From "Programming the Mobile Web" by Maximiliano Firtman.

I do understand the general sense of the sentence, which is: you should use CSS and clean markup. But it appears to me that there is a typo in this sentence and it has to be:

> You can do whatever you are thinking of **by** using **CSS and clean markup** for using
>    **a nested table**.

Is my assumption correct? If not, can someone construe the meaning of the sentence?

Comment: If you came here with google, go directly to the [linked, unfortunately closed, question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/113668/158175) and leave this confusing individual case alone!

Comment: Maybe you could confer to the thread about "using vs by using" (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217815/what-is-difference-between-using-and-by-using)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a mental pause after the *for*. The sentence means:

- Don't use a nested table for whatever it is you want to do; use CSS and clean markup instead.

Comment: Can't we say that a comma is missing after *for*?

Comment: The OP's extract is a good example of a *garden path sentence*; you don't realise you have been led astray until you get to the end of it. But I don't think it is best fixed with a comma. This may be more apparent if we look at a simpler version of the same construction: *You can make a webpage, using Dreamweaver*. I can't quite explain to my own satisfaction why this doesn't work for me, and may submit this as a question in its own right.

Answer (score 3):

The basic sentence structure is "You can do X using Y", where X is "whatever you are thinking of using a nested table for" and Y is "CSS and clean markup"

Answer (score 3):

I would assume the author inserted a silent comma in their head after the "for" and forgot to write it:

> You can do whatever you are thinking of using a nested table **for,**
>   using CSS and clean markup.

Which still doesn't scan nicely to me. I would personally write it as

"You can use CSS and clean markup to achieve anything you can do with a nested table"

Answer (score -2):

The author wanted to say that one could do things in web programming using CSS and Clean Markup like `<div>` instead of messing it up by using nested table tags .
So the sentence formation should have been

> You can do whatever you are thing of using CSS and clean Markup instead of nested table

or

> You can do whatever you are thing of using a nested table, by using CSS and clean MarkUp.

Comment: *thing* is most definitely the wrong word.

Comment: I am sure i am not, i am a software engineer therefore i can be sure that it is what author actually wanted to convey. Developing a webpage using nested table tags gets messy so it is advised to use clean html tags and css for developing it