# Using Vs. By using?

Tags: prepositions

> - He killed him (by) using a meat cleaver.
> - the gene editing methods (by) using a tool derived from a bacterial immune system called CRISPR.
> - he hit his wife (by) using his ring

These sentences are taken from a different books

The preposition I inserted into sentences are not really existed. My question is why do people not use the preposition ‘by’ in these situations?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is difference between “using” and “by using”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/217815)

Comment: @MetaEd you are right , but this point are not clarified enough to understand.

Comment: A duplicate question will be closed. A good way to get a better answer on the existing question is to offer a [bounty on it](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). This will get new attention to the question. There is even a place to explain why you offered a bounty.